# How Can I Disable Firestore Offline Cache?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm gonna release my app today but I have a problem with Firestore.

When I made a mistake on documents, for example, if I write the key name wrong or when I miss a key&value in a document, my app is crashing because of it is not matching model.

I'm updating and fixing it instantly but it is still occurring. When I print results on the console, old result is still coming from firebase, it was not updated.

I tried to disable offline cache but it is still the same.

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
dbCollectionPosts.settings = settings
```

And here is my readData function:

```
func readData() {
        dbCollectionPosts.collection("konular").addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }else {
                print("read success")
            }

            documentSnapshot!.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                // Real time create from server

                if (diff.type == .added) {
                    let model = try! FirestoreDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: diff.document.data())
                    self.data.append(model)
                }

                if (diff.type == .removed) {
                    let docId = diff.document.documentID
                    if let indexOfToRemove = self.data.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == docId} ) {
                        self.data.remove(at: indexOfToRemove)
                        print("removed: \(docId)")
                    }
                }

                // Real time modify from server
                if (diff.type == .modified) {
                    self.data = self.data.map { (eachData) -> Post in
                        let data = eachData
                        if data.id == diff.document.documentID {
                            return try! FirestoreDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: diff.document.data())
                        }else {
                            return eachData
                        }
                    }
                }
             }

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the cache in order to defend against old data in document isn't recommended.  Your code should instead defend itself against unexpected data in documents.  Validate everything before you use it.

Even if you manage to clear or disable the cache once to fix this, the problem will just happen again the next time you make a change to the structure of the documents in Firestore.  In general, if you expect that documents might change over time, client code should always check to see if expected fields are present and the field data is of the correct type.  This is called defensive programming - check everything before using it.

Comment: thanks for information Doug :) I know and I want to use offline mode with cache too but in this way when I made a mistake while adding new document, I must delete collection and create new one because old one is still returning old data if I updated it too.

Comment: Yes, that's why your code has to be defensive.  There is no easy way around this.

Comment: If I defend against data in the document, it is still not a solution to solve this problem. Because it is not updating results and I must create a new one with an unique name. Why it is still returning old data I still don't have any idea about it. Anyway, thanks for reply again :) I'm gonna wait little bit more to find a solution. If I can't find, I'm gonna create new collection :/